# How can I enable Confirm Button on input in sweet alert 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I need to disable the confirm button when the user hasn't changed any value in the text box inside the sweet alert and enable it only when the value in the text box has changed but I can't seem to find a way for this. here's my code:

```
swal({
            title: 'Please Enter Page Name',
            input: 'text',
            inputValue: PageName,
            confirmButtonText: 'Save',
            onOpen: function (){
                swal.disableConfirmButton(); //this disables the button
            }
            preConfirm: function (Name) {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    resolve();
                })
            },
            allowOutsideClick: false
        })
```

I used `onOpen` to fire the `swal.disableConfirmButton();` method but I don't know where to use `swal.enableConfirmButton();`. is there any function like `onInput` or something similar? If yes how to use that to achieve the desired result?

here's a codepen of what I have achieved so far.

https://codepen.io/zeeshanadilbutt/pen/NLvmZz?editors=0010

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with what's working so far?

Comment: @DragonBorn here's the codepen https://codepen.io/zeeshanadilbutt/pen/NLvmZz?editors=0010

everything is good I just need to disable the Save button when nothing is typed in the text box and enable it when a user types something

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since there is no `onInput` or something similar for `input: text`, you can use `getInput` inside `onOpen` and add an *event listener* to that to enable or disable your `button` accordingly.

Check the working snippet.

```js
swal({
  input: 'text',
  onOpen: function () {
    swal.disableConfirmButton();
    swal.getInput().addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      if(e.target.value === '') {
        swal.disableConfirmButton();
      } else {
        swal.enableConfirmButton();
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2"></script>
```

Comment: I thought about this and this seems the only solution to this. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: You don't need jQuery to add event listeners :) I simplified the code.

Comment: @LimonMonte much better! :)

Comment: @LimonMonte The code is much cleaner now. I have updated the explanation according.

Answer (score 2):

We can enable/disable the confirm button via `getConfirmButton` and `didOpen` ([this](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/1496) part is not on documentation)

> SweetAlert2 v11

```js
Swal.fire({
            title: 'Alert',
            didOpen: function () {
                Swal.getConfirmButton().setAttribute('disabled', 'true')
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

For future seekers...

Both answers didn't work for me. But @rb_19 's answer gave me a path on how to proceed.

Actually, `Swal.getConfirmButton()` returns the HTML Element for the button, so `Swal.getConfirmButton().setAttribute('disabled', 'true')` works but  `Swal.getConfirmButton().setAttribute('disabled', 'false')` doesn't.

`disableConfirmButton()` and `enableConfirmButton()` sounds deprecated, those functions doesn't exists in latest version (11.7.32).

So for disabling i used `removeAttribute` together with `didOpen` event as in example below

```
if (e.target.value != inputValidationText) {
  swal.getConfirmButton().setAttribute("disabled", "true");
} else {
  swal.getConfirmButton().removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

`onOpen` also seems deprecated.

Using `didOpen` only didn't allow me to start the component as disabled, so i used `willOpen` together.

Full code

```js
swal.fire({
      title: message,
      input: 'text',
      willOpen: function () {
        swal.getConfirmButton().setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
      },
      didOpen: function () {
        swal.getInput().addEventListener('keyup', function (e: any) {
          if (e.target.value != inputValidationText) {
            swal.getConfirmButton().setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
          } else {
            swal.getConfirmButton().removeAttribute('disabled');
          }
        });
      },
      showDenyButton: true,
      showCancelButton: showCancelButton,
      confirmButtonText: confirmationText,
      denyButtonText: denyText,
    });
  }
```

edit: Confirmed deprecated https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/pull/1497

I hope it somehow helps